# Why isn't my switch block (switching on $(e.target) .attr("class")) working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why this code doesn't work..

All i want is to have simple event delegation to assign one event listener.

it only alerts, it doesn't animate.
Please let me know whats wrong here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $("img");

$("span").click(function(e){
  var targetClicked = $(e.target).attr('class');
  //the alert works fine
  alert(targetClicked)

switch(targetClicked){
// i deleted the rest of the cases
    case d:img.stop(false,true);
  break;
    case e:img.slideDown().animate({"width":200, height:200, opacity:0.4,});
  break; 
  //nothings works here as well
    case f:alert("hi");
  break;
 }
 });         
});
```

Comment: Can you please describe HOW it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are `d` and `e` in your `switch` statement `case` conditions?  The way you're code is written right now, they're being treated as variables and your code is probably blowing up with a "'d' is undefined" error.

If you want to switch on the class names `"d"` and `"e"`, then you need to use the class names as strings:

```
switch (targetClicked) {
  case "d":
    //...
    break;
  case "e":
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: +1 Danget...I was typing a similar response and got a phone call from my credit card company =P

Comment: Haha, I can't count the number of times I've seen that dreaded "you lost the typing race" banner :P